# Using a contextual drawer for form options on mobile

Tags: forms, ios

I'm designing an app for submitting media content to a site. This app is HTML5 for both Android and iOs and it is being developed with PhoneGap. The example below is for the iOS layout.

Do you see this pattern correct, could it work? Do you have any concerns about this approach? It's about using a contextual drawer to set up a some options of the form.

[image: iOS example, contextual drawer]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any specific reason for having this in i drawer rather than a popup? I just don't see the benefit.

With a drawer you're used to expand/collapse it using a dedicated button or a bezel swipe (hopefully both), but here you request it with an in-line button. It really goes against established conventions when using this type of interactive artifact.

Based on the background you provided here I'd definitely suggest you'd look into using a more conventional selection control, like a popup.

Comment: Thanks! The problem I found with the popup is that... for example, I have another button to select artists, and it have more than a hundred items. An autocompleter is not good enough for the client that I working for.

Answer (score 2):

This is quickly becoming a popular pattern (though I'm not sure it has a name yet) - see https://medium.com/design-ux/bc190d62eff5 and https://medium.com/mobile-first-responsive-design/bbd6c04f09e1 for example implementations and rationale behind using it.

PS - The first article covers the specific problem that you have with selecting from a very large number of artists.

Comment: Nice! thanks, these are very interesting and informative articles.